# Remuneration issues after international relocation

Tags: salary, relocation, expenses

About 6 months ago I was fortunate enough to be given the opportunity to move abroad with my company. I have successfully relocated, but have encountered two problems related to remunerations:

1. Expenses. As part of the relocation agreement I was given £2000 for 'valid relocation expenses'. I asked for clarification on what this constitutes and received an email from the COO saying that I could spend it on whatever I liked, this was confirmed in a face to face meeting with him and a member of the HR team. 
   Since moving, I submitted expenses, had push back from HR, & our Chief of Staff (who joined a month ago) has informed me that the new Relocation Guidelines (put in place by him) state I can spend £500 on whatever I like, and £1500 on what the government considers to be tax deductible relocation expenses. Fortunately, I have not spent on anything outside of what the government considers to be tax deductible relocation expenses just yet ,so am not out of pocket, but had planned to. I was advised to do so by a member of HR department in place of shipping some of my possessions over, which was deemed too expensive. 
   My issue here is that I have made decisions based on the original agreement, which has now been changed.
2. Salary. As part of my relocation agreement, I received a salary increase. After completing my location I was accidentally paid my old salary. The company offered to pay me the difference when I informed them of this mistake. Unfortunately, they paid the difference out as a bonus which subjected me to a much higher rate of tax. I contacted the finance/HR department to ask if I would get that money back from the government at the end of the financial year, or if I would be reimbursed some other way. They advised me to seek advice from a tax advisor. I feel this is unreasonable, because I'm out of pocket because of their mistake, not mine, or the governments.

I'm in a position now where the HR Team, Chief of Staff and Finance team are ignoring me. I feel like I may have alienated myself from them during the process of raising these concerns. My next step is too raise this to my boss, who is in a C-level position in the company - I'm not sure if it's worth wasting his time though, and risking further alienating myself from other departments. Should I take this further?

Comment: What is the country in question? Tax implications differ between countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having gone through the process of relocation and battling bureaucracy, I feel your pain.

Here's what I would do.

1. The policy.  Ignore this problem.  Someone, somewhere, screwed up. A new policy has been put in place. Yes, they are idiots. Yes, it could have been costly for you. It wasn't.  It's annoying, but if you suffered no harm, it's not a battle **worth** fighting.  Even if you "won" you wouldn't gain anything.
2. Pay. I assume you pay tax via PAYE? This is definitely the company's responsibility.  A bonus shouldn't have been taxed any differently to your normal pay - you would still pay Income Tax, NI, & Student Loan repayments on it.  So I don't see how you would have lost out financially. What may be different is the amount paid into your pension (if you have one) and the salary they have on record for you if you want a raise next year.

They are right in the sense that HMRC will check how much you've been paid over the total year and then refund you if you've over-paid.  Yes, the Tax Man *does* give money back!

On to the final point, should you raise this?  It is unlikely that you will lose out financially - but you have been inconvenienced and put through some stress.  Your boss doesn't want you running off to the competition because you feel badly treated.

In one of your regular catch ups, you should explain the situation in the simplest possible terms. Don't focus on who has screwed up - talk about how it has affected you.  Don't get angry - just calmly say something like:

> I feel very badly let down by the company over this whole relocation experience. I'm still not sure that I've been paid the correct amount, and I'm worried that I will be out of pocket.  Can you suggest who in payroll I need to speak to in order to correct these mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for this - very sensible advice. Unfortunately, it's not the HMRC I'm dealing with but the IRS (US), from what I understand bonuses are subject to 55% tax. I'm going to take the advice of speaking to my boss in our next regular catch up. Cheers.

Comment: @John, I am in the US and none of my bonuses have ever been taxed at a higher rate when I filed my taxes. They care about total adjusted income (after tax deductions) not the source of income in determining actual taxes. The payroll program that your company uses may calculate at that rate to ensure you had enough taken out to cover the taxes because the additonal income might push you into a higher tax bracket. Check with an accountant but I do not think you can get the money back until you file your taxes if it has already been sent to the government.

Comment: I believe (for the US), taxes are withheld based on computing an implied annual salary based payment and the time interval.  So your special payment looked like you make a huge salary and your taxes were withheld accordingly.  When you finally do your taxes based on what you really earned for that year, you should get a tax return which would rectify the situation.  My bonus checks have always been heavily taxed but I get it back in the end.  It is unfortunate that your corrected compensation got treated this way, but I think you will have to wait until you file your taxes to get your money.

Answer (score 2):

Before you "pursue" this any further you need to be clear about what you want to achieve and what the desired outcome is. You can bring it up with your boss but that only makes sense if you have something specific that you want your boss to do. Otherwise you are just whining.

In this situation it seems unclear what you want. An apology from the HR department that they changed the policy? A letter that states they will reimburse you for any tax disadvantages due to the payment error?

Both don't seem desirable. The first one will just generate bad blood and the second would be frightfully complicated to execute: how exactly is determined what the damage was (if any) and who has the burden of proof?

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to pursue it, i would not mention that you have financial problems now, it puts a bad light on your money management skills and might reflect on your ability to do your job and lead to bad performance reviews, missed promotions, etc.

Just state again what went wrong, and how you see they should fix it. Make sure that what you claim is correct, hearing out of the other answers sounds you might be wrong about the bonus.

If your plans for the 500+1500 have been different and you still want to follow through with them, talk to the responsible person and tell them you relied on the previous agreement and want to do XYZ. If your plans are not affected by the new police, just let it be.

Or if you feel like it, mention it and tell them they might wanna check if it maybe affects other employees.